# Grouping parent node based on child elements values and sequence number

Tags: xslt

I need to transform XML using xslt.

Logic:

Split the parent if the parent having different child address and append the sequence number with parent name. Also need line number for the child.
Here we may have number of parent nodes and each parent node may have more number of child nodes.

I have tried numerous ways to achieve this and I am stuck with generating sequence number in the foreach. So can any one try and give a solution for this.

Source XML as below:

```
<Data>
   <Parent>
      <Name>P1</Name>
      <Child>
        <Name>CName1</Name>
        <Address>Address1</Address>
      </Child>
      <Child>
        <Name>CName2</Name>
        <Address>Address2</Address>
      </Child>
      <Child>
        <Name>CName3</Name>
        <Address>Address1</Address>
      </Child>
   </Parent>

   <Parent>
     <Name>P2</Name>
       <Child>
         <Name>CName1</Name>
         <Address>Address1</Address>
       </Child>
   </Parent>
</Data>
```

The target XML should be as below:

```
<Data>
  <Parent>
     <Name>P1_1</Name>
     <Address>Address1</Address>
     <Child>
       <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
       <Name>CName1</Name>
     </Child>
     <Child>
        <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
        <Name>CName3</Name>
     </Child>
  </Parent>

  <Parent>
      <Name>P1_2</Name>
      <Address>Address2</Address>
      <Child>
         <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
         <Name>CName2</Name>
      </Child>
  </Parent>

  <Parent>
      <Name>P2_1</Name>
      <Address>Address1</Address>
      <Child>
          <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
          <Name>CName1</Name>
       </Child>
  </Parent>
</Data>
```

Comment: Please format the code with {} button

Comment: For grouping problems you really need to tell us whether you can use XSLT 2.0 or whether you're stuck with XSLT 1.0. Grouping is *MUCH* easier with 2.0. Also, if you've solved part of the problem (grouping) and are stuck with the other part (numbering) then it's helpful to show us how far you got - it might require a fairly small tweak, or your approach might have been completely misguided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This XSLT 1.0 transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:key name="kAddress" match="Child" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', Address)" />

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Parent">
    <xsl:variable name="parent" select="." />
    <xsl:for-each select="Child[
      generate-id()
      = 
      generate-id(key('kAddress', concat(generate-id($parent), '|', Address))[1])
    ]">
      <Parent>
        <Name><xsl:value-of select="concat(../Name, '_', position())" /></Name>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Address" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="
          key('kAddress', concat(generate-id($parent), '|', Address))
        " />
      </Parent>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Child">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
      <LineNumber><xsl:value-of select="position()" /></LineNumber>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::Address)]" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Generates the following output for your sample:

```
<Data>
    <Parent>
        <Name>P1_1</Name>
        <Address>Address1</Address>
        <Child>
            <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
            <Name>CName1</Name>
        </Child>
        <Child>
            <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
            <Name>CName3</Name>
        </Child>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
        <Name>P1_2</Name>
        <Address>Address2</Address>
        <Child>
            <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
            <Name>CName2</Name>
        </Child>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
        <Name>P2_1</Name>
        <Address>Address1</Address>
        <Child>
            <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
            <Name>CName1</Name>
        </Child>
    </Parent>
</Data>
```

Comment: +1 I would use Childs by Parent and Adress just for readability