# Group by one child node and combine values of other child nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

Below an example of my current XML:

```
<products>
    <product>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Name 1</name>
        <price>10.00</price>
        <size>M</size>
        <link>http://link1.com</link>
        <stock>1</stock>
    </product>
    <product>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Name 1</name>
        <price>10.00</price>
        <size>L</size>
        <link>http://link1.com</link>
        <stock>3</stock>
    </product>
    <product>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Name 1</name>
        <price>10.00</price>
        <size>XL</size>
        <link>http://link1.com</link>
        <stock>2</stock>
    </product>
    <product>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Name 2</name>
        <price>30.00</price>
        <size>M</size>
        <link>http://link2.com</link>
        <stock>3</stock>
    </product>
    <product>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Name 2</name>
        <price>30.00</price>
        <size>L</size>
        <link>http://link2.com</link>
        <stock>2</stock>
    </product>
</products>
```

I want to combine each product based on the `id` and remove the duplicates with XSLT.

If the `id` is the same, the nodes `name`, `price` and `link` are always the same.

The nodes `size`s and `stock` can be different if the `id` is the same. For these nodes (`size` and `stock`) these values should be *summed up* into the node (comma separated).

The result should look like this:

```
<products>
    <product>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Name 1</name>
        <price>10.00</price>
        <size>M,L,XL</size>
        <link>http://link1.com</link>
        <stock>1,3,2</stock>
    </product>
    <product>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Name 2</name>
        <price>30.00</price>
        <size>M,L</size>
        <link>http://link2.com</link>
        <stock>3,2</stock>
    </product>
</products>
```

I've searched and tried out several solutions but can't figure this one out.

Is there anyone who can help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add the XSLT version tag to your question, since it's relevant in grouping. Search for *grouping in XSLT 2.0* and you will find many examples. Search for *Muenchian grouping* if you are restricted to XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Similar questions/answers. **XSLT 1.0**: [Grouping parent node based on child elements...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670775/grouping-parent-node-based-on-child-elements-values-and-sequence-number), [Grouping XML nodes by attribute value...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243965/grouping-xml-nodes-by-attribute-value-in-xslt), [XLST transformation to XML grouping by key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443948/xslt-tranformation-to-xml-grouping-by-key), **XSLT 2.0**: [How to use for-each-group...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19115109/how-to-use-for-each-group-in-xsl)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. In the end I found this solution which helped me out perfectly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768402/xslt-concat-fields-together